# Highcharts with multiple dataLabels

Tags: php, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to display transaction status for different months. The chart is displaying fine. To show the number of transactions for each month, I have placed a datalabel on top of each column. The code is given below:

```
  $(function () { 
                $('#hc').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: <?php echo $type ; ?>,
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 35
            },               

            title: {
                text: 'Transaction Status',
                x: -20 
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {                    
                categories: <?php echo $monnth_series ?>

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Transactions'
                },                  
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,                       
                    color: '#fff',
                    style: {fontWeight: 'bold'},
                    formatter: function() {return this.y},  
                    y: -5,                                              
                    rotation: 360
                },                  
                column: {                        
                    pointPadding: .2,
                    groupPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 1
                  }                  
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name  +': '+ this.y; +'</b>'

                }
            },
            credits: { enabled: false },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -6,
                y: 90,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            series: <?php echo $series_data ?>
         });
            });
```

Now I want to place another datalabel on the body of the column which will show the type of the transaction. 
If I try

```
formatter: function() {return this.series.name},    
inside: true,
```

then the datalabel shows correctly but the datalabel on top of the column does not show up.

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: I have to ideas how you can make your chart. First is to use stackLabels (you need to set stacking of your columns to true). Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/99rbh2qj/15/

Another idea is to use renderer.text() for adding new labels in your chart. Here you can find information about this method: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text